# Computational complexity of the lasso (lars vs coordinate descent)

Tags: lasso, lars, time-complexity

The lasso can be computed with the LARS or Coordinate Descent algorithm.

What is their computational complexity and when one is quicker than the other?

Answer (score 4):

I realize it's quite late to give an answer but maybe someone will find it useful.

Here is a nice talk by Trevor Hastie about the [coordinate descent](http://videolectures.net/kdd08_hastie_rpcd/). He compares (among others) his two R packages: `glmnet` (using coordinate descent) and `lars` (using LARS).

It's shown that coordinate descent is faster in each setting: $p>N, p<N$ and sparse or dense data. There are some examples featuring both simulated and real data.