# Computational complexity of L1 LASSO

Tags: regression, lasso, time-complexity

I am interest in the constrained L1 Lasso problem:
$$\min_{\beta\in \mathbb{R}^p:\sum_{i\in[p]}|\beta_i|=1} \|X\beta -s\|^2,  (1)$$
for design matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ and target $s\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
In particular, I am interested in the setting where there are more features than examples, i.e. $p>n$ (and potentially $p\gg n$). Is there any algorithm that solves $(1)$ up to error, say $\epsilon$, with a computational complexity of order $O(p n^2 \log \epsilon^{-1})$ or something similar.

Specific requirements:

- I want an algorithm with a sample complexity that scales linearly (up to potentially log factors) with the number of features $p$. For example, I do not want a complexity that scales with $O(p^k)$ for $k\geq 2$.
- I specifically want a linearly-convergent algorithm, i.e. one that requires $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$ iterations instead of $O(poly(1/\epsilon))$.

Note that the answer given in [Computational complexity of the lasso (lars vs coordinate descent)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218087/computational-complexity-of-the-lasso-lars-vs-coordinate-descent) does not give me what I want; it mentions an algorithm with a computational complexity that scales with $p^3 + n p^2$ (if I adapt their notation to my setting).

Comment: I believe you can find $p-n$ redundant features with $O(pn^2)$ effort and, after eliminating them, $p$ effectively is reduced to $n$ and $O(p^3)$ is reduced to $O(pn^2).$

Comment: How to do you remove the $p -n$ redundant features with $O(pn^2)$ effort? Is there a reference you can link me? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: How would you ensure that the value of the problem does not increase once you remove some features this way?

Comment: [Related thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76518), possibly containing some helpful links.